# How to add a static image to theme?

Tags: theming, media

I'm very amateur in theming. Using [Basic](http://drupal.org/project/basic) theme for Drupal 6, I try to add an image to the very top of the page. (Something like repeating flags [here](http://www.andthewinnerisnt.com/)) 
However, when I add

```
<img src="images/flags.png"/>
```

to the upper side of page.tpl.php, the image has proper permissions but does not show up. No surprise though since the image is hyperlinked as

```
http:// 127.0.0.1/drupal6/content/images/flags.png
```

I have also tried defining a  div class="flags" at the top of page.tpl.php and then introduce the image as the div's background-image url('images/flags.png'). No success either.

Direct insertion of static images used to work on my other theme. So got really perplexed and appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is the image saved? You need to create an absolute path to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your theme images in a directory in your theme; let's call it `img`.

Then you can load them like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME'); ?>/img/flags.png">
```

Hope this helps.

(More info at [drupal_get_path();](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/6))

Comment: It worked Thanks! However I still can not theme it. I'v added class="flags" into image tag and defined the class in default.css as .flags{background-repeat:repeat-x;}. However the image does not repeat. Any ideas?

Comment: That's not how `img` elements work. Set the background to a block element (i.e., a `<div>` using CSS. If you have a .css file in your theme, you just have to do `.flags{background: url('img/flags.png') repeat-x;}`

Comment: Strangely, enclosing the image in a <div class="flags"... and then adding background: url('img/flags.png') repeat-x;} to layout.css did not work. So my workaround was to directly add  width="100%" inside the <img> tag and use a wider image instead. I know it is not ideal, though. any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Firebug or Google Chrome? It'd it'd help a lot if you're able to identify whether that declaration in layout.css is even visible to the div in question. Also, if at first you don't succeed -- try clearing the cache.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the div header and css background image to put that kind of image.
Anyway if you want to put a static image in the theme you can add

```
<img src="<?php print $GLOBALS['base_url'];?>/images/flag.png" />
```

$GLOBALS['base_url'] is the url of the website (http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/folder if it's in a subfolder)